# Apache Windows 10 ,404 Not Found Error (Wamp)

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I've installed php, mysql, apache with WAMP for windows 10. When I go to http://localhost there is not any problem, the appropriate page is shown. The server is up and running, but when I try to open http://localhost/test.php it gives me 404  not found error. By the way I've put the index.html and test.php into wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/htdocs. The server can access neither index.html in that directory nor test.php. Your help is welcome.

Comment: Did you check apache error logs ?

Comment: I think its port issue, apache uses port 80 and maybe it is reserved by some other services you can try by editing the configuration setting click on Wamp green icon on the notification area --> Apache --> httpd.conf find the Listen 0.0.0.0:80 and change it to 0.0.0.0:8080 then try to open your file as http://localhost:8080/test.php and I am sure it will work for you.
If you want to use the default configuration then you should find the services that use port 80 and release it by stoping its services

Comment: @ Ghufran Ataie I've controlled. First of all there is not the tray icon. Secondly I've checked only Apache uses port 80 in my computer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `The server can access neither ...`.  Looks like a permission issue - related to your `User` and `Group` directives and the access rights on the system.  Put `LogLevel debug` in your configuration, retry, and look at the error_log.  It will contain a lot of information, along with the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Selim Achour said I looked to the error logs and  I found that apache server wasp/ searching the test.php in a folder called wamp/www/test.php. When I move the test.php from htdocs/test.php to www/test.php it works perfectly. I was following instructions from a book that I'd been reading. In that book's instructions, it is clearly stated that you should move test.php into htdocs. That was what got me confused. Thank you all for your effort.

The error: Sat Sep 26 13:14:03.134587 2020] [php7:error] [pid 8220:tid 1204] [client ::1:6466] script 'C:/wamp64/www/test.php' not found or unable to stat

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted instead of adding "solved" to the post title

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski I can't accept it. It says that you can accept your own answer tomorrow.

Comment: I meant "as soon as it allows" so tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 0):

WAMPServer's DocumentRoot folder is `C:\wamp64\www` BUT You should NEVER place your scripts into that folder!!!

Make a subfolder and use that i.e. `C:\wamp\www\test1` put your test.php in there and run using `locahost/test1/test.php`

Better still create a Virtual Host for all your test areas and development site folders. See [THE NEED for VIRTUAL HOSTS](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) and then [WAMPServer 3 Create a Virtual Host, the easy way](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,146746)